# React-Checking and Unchecking of CheckBox

Tags: reactjs

I have a component in which there is a checkbox and on on Changed event of checkbox ,i want to display a message saying it is checked or not .
There is no error in VS Code ,and when i tried debugging the code did fire on Changed event and called the tick function and call the setstate,but then when i step into next line ,it goes into some internal React javascript files which i find hard to understand ,to figure out the problem . Presently i get a checkbox ,but on checking or unchecking the message does not change

```
  import React,{ Component } from 'react';
class Checked extends Component{
constructor(props)
{
    super(props);    
this.state= {check: true};


}
tick()
{
 this.setState({check:!this.state.check});
    }

   render(){
        var msg="";
       if ( this.state.check=true)
        {
            msg="checked";
        }
        else
        {
            msg="unchecked";
        }
      return(<div><input type="checkbox" onChange={this.tick.bind(this)} defaultChecked={this.state.check} ></input>
      <h1>checkbox is {msg}</h1>
      </div> );
   }
}

export default Checked;
```

Comment: `if ( this.state.check=true )` condition is wrong...it must be `if ( this.state.check == true)`

Comment: it is working now ,thanks Jeevan

Answer (score -1):

You can also add the logic in the function, this implementation works for me

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';


class Checked extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);


    this.state = {
      checkBox: true,
      checkedMsg: ''
    }
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      checkBox: !this.state.checkBox
    })

    this.state.checkBox ? this.setState({ checkedMsg: 'checked' }) : this.setState({ checkedMsg: 'unchecked' })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onClick={this.tick}
          defaultChecked={this.state.check}
        />
        <h1>checkbox is {this.state.checkedMsg}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Checked;

render(<Checked />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: You should keep your state minimal. In this case, checkedMsg shouldn't be another state, because it's calculable from state.check.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Tran, your right I just read that in Thinking in React documentation